# Use cases of std::byte

Tags: c++, c++17

The recent addition of `std::byte` to C++17 got me wondering why this type was even added to the standard at all. Even after reading [the cppreference reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) it's use cases don't seem clear to me.

The only use case I can come up with is that it more clearly expresses intent, as `std::byte` should only be treated as a collection of bits instead of a character type such as `char` which we used for both purposes before. 
Meaning that:

this:

```
std::vector<std::byte> memory;
```

Is more clear than this:

```
std::vector<char> memory;
```

Is this the only use case and reason it was added to the standard or am I missing a big point here?

Comment: [This](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0298r0.pdf) seems to be the document behind the addition. It has a section for the motivations behind the proposal.

Comment: There are subtle problems that can bite you using `char` such as it is implementation defined if it is signed or not. Signed `char` can produce a surprising value if it gets cast to an `int` (due to sign extension). So you could write code that works on some systems but not others. Also you can accidentally do math on `char` (because it's an integer) which won't be a problem for `std::byte`. So this could potentially benefit any code that performs serialization/streaming data such as networking.

Comment: @Galik: when was the last time you "accidentally" did the math on something? Generally if I write `+` it doesn't happen by accident.

Comment: My rationalization for the addition of `std::byte` to the standard with its current definition is that the procedure for standard definition of C++ is clearly broken.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Anything that can go wrong, will have gone wrong at least a few times in any large body of source code. Unless you have a team of programmers that never write the wrong variable name by mistake.

Comment: @Galik: safeguards are important, but come at a cost in usability, that's why generally you introduce them for actual problems, not imagined ones. When was the last time I overflew an array? Last week. Use after free? Doesn't happen *that* often to modern code I write, but I fixed plenty of bugs related to memory and ownership. Memory leaks? Concurrency bugs? It's all stuff that happens frequently. Now I'll ask you again, when was the last time you *accidentally* did math on something? Personally I cannot remember, and instead I wrote a decent amount of bit fiddling code that needs arithmetic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The only use case I can come up with is that it more clearly expresses intent

I think it was one of the reasons. [This paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0298r3.pdf) explains the motivation behind `std::byte` and compares its usage with the usage of *char*:

> *Motivation and Scope*
>
> Many programs require byte-oriented access to
>   memory. Today, such programs must use either the char, signed char, or
>   unsigned char types for this purpose. However, these types perform a
>   “triple duty”. Not only are they used for byte addressing, but also as
>   arithmetic types, and as character types. This multiplicity of roles
>   opens the door for programmer error – such as accidentally performing
>   arithmetic on memory that should be treated as a byte value – and
>   confusion for both programmers and tools. **Having a distinct byte type
>   improves type-safety, by distinguishing byte-oriented access to memory
>   from accessing memory as a character or integral value. It improves
>   readability.**
>
> **Having the type would also make the intent of code
>   clearer to readers (as well as tooling for understanding and
>   transforming programs). It increases type-safety by removing
>   ambiguities in expression of programmer’s intent, thereby increasing
>   the accuracy of analysis tools.**

Another reason is that [std::byte](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) is restricted in terms of operations which can be performed on this type:

> Like char and unsigned char, it can be used to access raw memory
>   occupied by other objects (object representation), but unlike those
>   types, **it is not a character type and is not an arithmetic type**. A
>   byte is only a collection of bits, and **only bitwise logic operators
>   are defined for it**.

which ensures an additional type safety as it is mentioned in the paper above.

Comment: IMO the fact that `std::byte` is not an arithmetic type is just a solution in search of a problem. I cannot think at a situation when I ever worked on a sequence of bytes *just to use bitwise operations*. If I want a sequence of opaque bytes I use `void *` (although it has the downside of pointer arithmetic not working correctly), if I want to do low level bytes manipulation give me the whole arsenal of operations. We already have a type that is great at being a "raw byte": it's called `unsigned char`. Bitwise and arithmetic operations work in a guaranteed and unsurprising way, ...

Comment: ... `unsigned char` pointers can already alias any other pointer (without polluting the whole standard with an extra magic type), pointer arithmetic already works fine. The only problem with `unsigned char` is that it's a PITA to write, is a two-tokens name (so function style casts & co. are problematic) and that its name may not be as suggestive. These problems are solved by doing `namespace std { typedef unsigned char byte; }` - which incidentally is essentially what has been done in countless code bases that manipulate raw bytes.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: "*These problems are solved by doing...*" Nonsense. `unsigned char*` could be a byte array or a character array. That "solution" doesn't allow you to actually different between the two; it's no better than a comment that says that a parameter is a byte array. Furthermore, because of the lack of distinction, the standard requires that `unsigned char*` can alias freely. This breaks a number of optimizations on functions that take strings as opposed to generic byte arrays. Only byte arrays should be able to alias freely. A strong typedef is essential to fixing this.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, inserting anything like that into the std namespace is undefined behavior, so that's not even an acceptable solution from the get go.

Comment: @MárioFeroldi: of course nobody does that into the `std` namespace, I just meant that everybody has his own shorter `typedef` for `unsigned char`.

Comment: @NicolBolas: nonsense, in virtually all the C and C++ standard libraries characters are plain `char` (whose signedness is idiotically implementation-defined, but we are digressing). "it's no better than a comment that says that a parameter is a byte array" which is perfectly fine; this necessity is entirely artificial. All the rest of your comment is pointless, given that the standard lets `char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char` and `std::byte` all to alias freely whatever other type, so I don't see how this "essential" strong typedef has changed anything in the aliasing situation.

Comment: Now, if you want to say that the character types should not have the aliasing wildcard and that there should have been a separate byte type, and only it should have the aliasing magic that's something we can discuss for another language (and I'll agree only if the `byte` type behaves like an unsigned integer), but unfortunately this isn't something you can change in C++, and adding a lame `std::byte` today only adds confusion.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: It's an essential *first step*. Later, once lots of code and APIs have converted to using `std::byte`, they could perhaps deprecate the aliasing, with the goal of eventually removing it. But unless you have a type that is distinct from a character array, there is no way to move towards undoing this aliasing. Also, `signed char` doesn't participate in aliasing.

Comment: Deprecating aliasing for char types is something that cannot be done, period. It's a silent death trap that would break tons of perfectly legal code, and would be the final confirmation that the committee has jumped the shark. There are way more pragmatic, opt-in approaches to the problem (in the style of `restrict`) - when you can actually measure it, aliasing is way overstated as a problem.